# Write Variable javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

[image][image]i am make ajax request on select box  to return cities dependent on countries
but when i return old and test if this id of cities contain on array i can't write
the java script variable " key " that refer to city id on this line
i am attached photo of code with question
please help me

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="country_id"]').on('change', function() {
            var countryID = $(this).val();
            if(countryID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{!! url('/admin/getCities') !!}/'+countryID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="ship_to_ids[]"]').empty();
                        console.log('ok');
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="ship_to_ids[]"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'" {{ (in_array( key , old( "ship_to_ids",
                             isset($product) ? ($product->ship_to_ids?:[]) : []))) ? "selected" : " " }}>'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="ship_to_ids[]"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i am edit the question and two photos to the code and the error

Answer (score 0):

Ok the tricky part is here

```
{{ (in_array( key , ...
```

`in_array` is looking for a variable as first parameter and you gave it a constant `key` so you need to pass your `key` variable.

**Updated**

you can do so in your javascript code

```
var option = '<option value="'+ key +'" {{ (in_array( ":key" , old( "ship_to_ids", isset($product) ? ($product->ship_to_ids?:[]) : []))) ? "selected" : " " }}>'+ value +'</option>';
option = option.replace(':key', key)
                                
$('select[name="ship_to_ids[]"]').append(option);
```

Comment: can u write example like it ?